# Get error when I want to withdraw ethers from my contract

Tags: web3js, ether

I have a contract in which, I want to withdraw my ethers using a function.
It works fine in remix, but in web3 It does not work and throws VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode","code":-32000
note that, I have enough ether in my contract

my contract(sol v.8) code is :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestEther {

address payable wallet;

fallback() external {}

constructor(address _wallet) {
                                                                
  wallet = payable(_wallet);                                   
}

function sendEther() public payable {
    
}  

function withdraw(uint _amount) public {

    require(_amount <= address(this).balance, "not enough");
    payable(wallet).transfer(_amount);
 }
}
```

web 3 code using react (removed the extra codes here):

```
sendEther = (amount) => {
this.state.ether.methods.sendEther().send({ from: accounts[0], value: 
amount }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
 })
}

withdraw = (amount) => {
this.state.ether.methods.withdraw(amount).send({from: 
accounts[0]}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
 })
}
```

The Send ether method works fine, but the withdraw doesn't work with Web3 (works fine in Remix)

I use the same way in web3 to withdraw erc20 tokens like this, and it works fine. But it cant withdraw ether.

Comment: What do you mean, withdraw ether ? What is the contract code ?

Comment: @ Florian Castelian It is in the question. look at the withdraw function

Answer (score 0):

Some how, this works fine in test networks like Rinkeby
I used ganache in remix and it still fails.

I think the problem is ganache, I don't know how to fix it. But for some reasons ganache doesn't support this line code:

```
anyAddress.transfer(amount);
```

maybe some one can find the answer